# Generating samples from different distributions in shiny

Tags: r, switch-statement, shiny

I am trying to create a shinyapp to generate different samples from some statistical distributions. My app contains a switch in order to specify the distribution and then it shows the inputs for the parameters.

I am not able to obtain anything! This is the ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Sampling"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("popDistX", "X",
                  list("Normal" = "normal",
                       "Beta" = "beta",
                       "Gamma" = "gamma",
                       "Weibull" = "weibull"
                  )
      ),  

      numericInput("nX", 
                   "Tamaño muestral X:", 
                   min = 1, 
                   max = 400, 
                   value = 2),


      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'beta'",
        sliderInput("shape1", "Forma 1: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("shape2", "Forma 2: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'gamma'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'weibull'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'normal'",
        sliderInput("mean", "Media: ", min=0, max=400, value=0),
        sliderInput("sd", "Desviación típica: ", min=0.1, max=20, value=1, step=.1)
      )
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("histogram")
    )
  )
))
```

And the server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  DistX <- reactive( function() input$popDistX )

  nX <- reactive( function() input$nX )

  paramsX <- reactive( function() {
    switch(DistX(),
           "normal" = list(mean=input$mean, sd=ainput$sd),
           "beta" = list(shape1=input$shape1, shape2=input$shape2),
           "gamma" = list(shape=input$shape, scale=input$scale),
           "weibull" = list(shape=input$shape, scale=input$scale)
    )} )

  rdistX <- reactive( function() {
    switch(DistX(),
           "normal" = "rnorm",
           "beta" = "rbeta",
           "gamma" = "rgamma",
           "weibull" = "rweibull"
    )} )


  sampleDistX <- reactive( function()
      do.call(rdistX(), list(nX(), paramsX()))
  )

  output$n <- renderPlot({
    hist(sampleDistX())
  })

})
```

Please, any help?? It is important and I do not know where is my error...

Thank you very much in advance.
Julio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those switches seem a little unnecessary to me. You could just put them all in 1 reactive something like this should simplify your app (and still give you what you want):

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myDist <- reactive({
    if(input$popDistX == "normal"){
      rnorm(input$nX, input$mean, input$sd)

    } else if(input$popDistX == "beta"){
      rbeta(input$nX, input$shape1, input$shape2)

    } else if(input$popDistX == "gamma"){
      rgamma(input$nX, input$shape, input$scale)

    } else if(input$popDistX == "weibull"){
      rweibull(input$nX, input$shape, input$scale)

    }
  })

  output$histogram <- renderPlot({
    hist(myDist())
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Sampling"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("popDistX", "X",
                  list("Normal" = "normal",
                       "Beta" = "beta",
                       "Gamma" = "gamma",
                       "Weibull" = "weibull"
                  )
      ),  

      numericInput("nX", 
                   "Tamaño muestral X:", 
                   min = 1, 
                   max = 400, 
                   value = 2),


      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'beta'",
        sliderInput("shape1", "Forma 1: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("shape2", "Forma 2: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'gamma'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'weibull'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'normal'",
        sliderInput("mean", "Media: ", min=0, max=400, value=0),
        sliderInput("sd", "Desviación típica: ", min=0.1, max=20, value=1, step=.1)
      )
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("histogram")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! In this way it is easier to understand! Really thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is not one, but multiple errors:

First, a few typos: `"histogram"` instead of `"n"` (or `output$n` instead of `output$histogram` if you prefer). There is a `ainput` instead of `input`.

More problematic: why pass functions to `reactive()` and not expressions directly?

With those minor fixes, the following code should work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Sampling"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("popDistX", "X",
                  list("Normal" = "normal",
                       "Beta" = "beta",
                       "Gamma" = "gamma",
                       "Weibull" = "weibull"
                  )
      ),  
      numericInput("nX", 
                   "Tamaño muestral X:", 
                   min = 1, 
                   max = 400, 
                   value = 2),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'beta'",
        sliderInput("shape1", "Forma 1: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("shape2", "Forma 2: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'gamma'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'weibull'",
        sliderInput("shape", "Forma: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05),
        sliderInput("scale", "Escala: ", min=0.1, max=10, value=1, step=0.05)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.popDistX == 'normal'",
        sliderInput("mean", "Media: ", min=0, max=400, value=0),
        sliderInput("sd", "Desviación típica: ", min=0.1, max=20, value=1, step=.1)
      )
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("n")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  DistX <- reactive( input$popDistX )
  nX <- reactive( input$nX )
  paramsX <- reactive(  {
    switch(DistX(),
           "normal" = list(mean=input$mean, sd=input$sd),
           "beta" = list(shape1=input$shape1, shape2=input$shape2),
           "gamma" = list(shape=input$shape, scale=input$scale),
           "weibull" = list(shape=input$shape, scale=input$scale)
    )} )
  rdistX <- reactive(  {
    switch(DistX(),
           "normal" = "rnorm",
           "beta" = "rbeta",
           "gamma" = "rgamma",
           "weibull" = "rweibull"
    )} )
  sampleDistX <- reactive( 
    do.call(rdistX(), c(nX(), paramsX()))
  )
  output$n <- renderPlot({
    hist(sampleDistX())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```